# How can I extract non digit characters and digit characters in the end of a string?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a string that has the following structure:

digit-word(s)-digit.

For example:

2029 AG.IZTAPALAPA 2

I want to extract the word(s) in the middle, and the digit at the end of the string.

I want to extract AG.IZTAPALAPA **and** 2 in the same capture group to extract like:

AG.IZTAPALAPA 2

I managed to capture them as individual capture groups but not as a single:

```
town_state['municipality'] = town_state['Town'].str.extract(r'(\D+)', expand=False)

town_state['number'] = town_state['Town'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$', expand=False)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Though I don't know which language it is, doesn't it do the expected work by `'(\D+\d+)$'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can use a single capturing group for the example string to match a single "word" that consists of uppercase chars A-Z with an optional dot in the middle which can not be at the start or end followed by 1 or more digits.

```
\b\d+ ([A-Z]+(?:\.[A-Z]+)* \d+)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d+`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z]+` Match 1+ occurrences of an uppercase char A-Z
  - `(?:\.[A-Z]+)* \d+` Repeat 0+ times matching a dot and a char A-Z followed by matching 1+ digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1kRXky/1)

Or you can make the pattern a bit broader matching either a dot or a word character

```
\b\d+ ([\w.]+(?: [\w.]+)* \d+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PC8iBZ/1)

Comment: Either solution works, however, I have the following strings:
1. 2029 AG.IZTAPALAPA 2
2. 2029 AG.IZTAPALAPA

Your answer successfully extracts string 1, but when the digit is not at the end. It 'extracts' the string as Nan. 
Is there a way to make the last digits optional?

Comment: @AlejandroL You can make the space and digits part optional `\b\d+ ([A-Z]+(?:\.[A-Z]+)*(?: \d+)?)\b` See https://regex101.com/r/H2frul/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following simple regex:

[0-9]+\s([A-Z]+.[A-Z]+(?: [0-9]+)*)

Note:

(?: [0-9]+)* **will make it the last digital optional.**

Comment: Thank you, this is useful to capture them as separate groups in one line of code. However, I want to capture them as a whole group.